# only 5 posts are showing in wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress

please someone help me,
my wordpress site showing only 5 posts on home page,
this is my loop.php code 
i found the same question here but code was deffrent.

```
<?php
/**
 * If you are looking for the loop that's handling the single post page (single.php), check out loop-single.php
 **/


// $global_flag_to_hide_no_post_to_display - comes from page-category-big-grid.php and is a flag to hide the 'No posts to display' message if on category page there are between 1 and 5  posts
global $loop_module_id, $loop_sidebar_position, $global_flag_to_hide_no_post_to_display;

///if we are in wordpress loop; used by quotes in blocks to check if the blocks are displayed in blocks or in loop
td_global::$is_wordpress_loop = true;

$td_template_layout = new td_template_layout($loop_sidebar_position);

if (empty($loop_module_id)) {  //not sure if we need a default here
    $loop_module_id = 1;
}

$td_module_class = td_api_module::_helper_get_module_class_from_loop_id($loop_module_id);


//disable the grid for some of the modules
$td_module = td_api_module::get_by_id($td_module_class);
if ($td_module['uses_columns'] === false) {
    $td_template_layout->disable_output();
}


if (have_posts()) {
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        echo $td_template_layout->layout_open_element();

        if (class_exists($td_module_class)) {
            $td_mod = new $td_module_class($post);
            echo $td_mod->render();
        } else {
            td_util::error(__FILE__, 'Missing module: ' . $td_module_class);
        }

        echo $td_template_layout->layout_close_element();
        $td_template_layout->layout_next();
    endwhile; //end loop
    echo $td_template_layout->close_all_tags();


} else {
    /**
     * no posts to display. This function generates the __td('No posts to display').
     * the text can be overwritten by the template using the global @see td_global::$custom_no_posts_message
     */

    echo td_page_generator::no_posts();
}
```

please any one help me how to increase it to 10+
actually i dont have much knowledge of php so i m using theme.

Thanks for the help

Comment: what is in your index,php file

Comment: limited character allowed so i am not able to show the complete code

Comment: //prepare the loop variables
global $loop_module_id, $loop_sidebar_position;
$loop_module_id = td_util::get_option('tds_' . $template_id . '_page_layout', 15); //module 1 is default

Comment: you have to change the code bit  to show 10 posts

Answer (score 1):

There is a setting in the admin backend, page `Settings > Read` which says something like "max number of posts in blog pages" which you can change.

Comment: ya sir checked the value is 10

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the code bit. Check this link to get an idea about post number limitations. [link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50135/how-to-limit-the-number-of-posts-on-the-home-page)

If you got any error please check the codex.wordpress.org 
check this link to know about `posts_per_page`  [link to posts_per_page doc](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts)